# Worldwide Envrionmental Products EIS 5000 Analyser: “Communication Error with IOBoard”

Tags: fuel-system, computer

I have an old EIS 5000 fuel analyser which displays the error "Communication Error with IOBoard". The system was used a long time ago without problem until this problem came and was never solved. The only documentation I found is the user manual, but it doesn't go in such details (http://www.aircheckdavis.com/documents/UT_EIS5000-EIS7000_Analyzer_OwnerOperators_Manual(2012-10).pdf).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: First I would make sure all the board connectors are clean & tight - especially since it has not been used in a while.